# How to check duplicate value in same store

Tags: extjs

I have a JsonStore with the following fields:

```
name,
url,
text
```

how to do i check if there are any records having the same name as previous record?

records are considered if they have same name.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`collect`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-collect):

> Collects unique values for a particular dataIndex from this store.

For example:

```
var hasDuplicates = store.collect('name').length < store.getCount();
```